# How to send a .csv file from Local Machine(Getfile) to Hive(Puthiveql) in Apache Nifi using CURL?

Tags: mysql, curl, apache-nifi

I want to send .csv file or mysql table from Local Machine(GetFile) to Hive(PutHiveql) in Apache Nifi using CURL.Please let me know if there is any command to do this Using Curl.

Comment: Try this: https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/docs/dashdb/load/load-delimited-data-using-the-rest-api-and-curl/

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't make sense as formed. If you want to ingest the content of a CSV file into Apache NiFi, route and transform it, and eventually write it to a Hive table, your flow would be as follows:

```
GetFile -> ConvertRecord (CSVReader to AvroRecordSetWriter) -> [Optional processors] -> PutHiveStreaming
```

`PutHiveStreaming` expects the incoming flowfile content to be in Avro format, so the `ConvertRecord` processor will translate the ingested data into the correct syntax.

I am unsure of how `cURL` fits into this question at all. NiFi does provide the `InvokeHTTP` processor to allow arbitrary outgoing HTTP requests, as well as the `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor to invoke arbitrary command-line activity, including `cURL`. I don't know why you would need to invoke either in this flow. If you are asking how you could trigger the entire flow via an external `cURL` command, NiFi provides both `ListenHTTP` and `HandleHTTPRequest` processors which start local web servers and listen for incoming HTTP requests. You can connect these processors to a pair of `Wait`/`Notify` processors to control the flow of the ingested file data, as `GetFile` is a *source* processor, and does not allow incoming flowfiles to trigger it.